# PCAP - send packet to local server

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, pcap

I am trying to send a packet to local server (:80) using pcap. I bind the pcap to eth0, and send the packet using pcap_inject(..). I am testing this on ubuntu.

However, I can see the packet send out on eth0 (confirmed by tcpdump running on the same machine). The fields in the packet are:

Ethernet: 
dst mac: ff ff ff ff ff ff, 
src mac: "mac of the same server"

IP:
dst ip: "ip of the same server",
src ip: "ip of the different server where the return packets should go"

I am wondering if it is possible to use pcap to send packets to the server running on the same machine. Other words, does OS TCP stack see the packets sent by the pcap. If so, is there something wrong with the fields I have shown.

Thanks!